# Torch, how to select a subset of a tensor?

Tags: lua, torch

For example, I have a tensor `t = torch.rand(10,1)`. And I want to select the tensor subset of at the rows of `{1,3,7,9}` and concatenate them as new tensor. Is there any elegant way? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`:index`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-indexdim-index) method:

```
tens = torch.rand(10,1)
ind = torch.LongTensor{1,3,7,9}
subset = tens:index(1, ind)
```