# How to slice tensors with a predefined order in torch?

Tags: lua, torch

I have a dataset of length 10 `train = torch.range(1,10)`. I want to slice it in a random order defined by `p = torch.randperm(10)`.

To get slice by ranges one can do `a = train[{{1,3}}]` to get elements th first three elements. But lets say I want the the 2nd, 3rd and 9th elements. Can I get this without operating a for loop like this

```
for i = 1,3 do
  print(a[{ p[i] }])
end
```

where

```
p[1] = 2, p[2] = 3, p[3] = 9.
```

`a = train[{{ p[{{1,3}}] }}]` doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Torch, how to select a subset of a tensor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089868/torch-how-to-select-a-subset-of-a-tensor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one there's [index](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-indexdim-index), it however requires longTensors:

```
train = torch.range(1,10)
p = torch.randperm(10):long()
print(train:index(p))
```